# Node.js redirect CSS 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: css, node.js, redirect

When I use this redirect :

```
.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var url = req.originalUrl;
    if (url != "/login" && !req.session.email) {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
    next();
})
```

it looks like my CSS files can not load correctly, I want that they load with status **200** instead of **302** one :

[image]

Comment: What is your question? If you don't want to redirect CSS, change your code to skip CSS requests.

Comment: no, it looks like css can not load correctly,I want css could load with status 200, ths very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware is redirecting CSS requests.
You need to make it not do that.

You probably want to put that after your static files middleware, so that it won't run at all for static files.

Comment: my css files are in the public folder, and i set  this 'app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))'

Comment: Yes.  You probably want to run that middleware before you redirect other requests.

Comment: Middleware runs in the order that you make the `app.use()` calls.  You need to call the `serveStatic` middleware before your custom redirector.

Comment: that makes work, My code is in the wrong order.thank you, thanks ver much,thanks ver much